# Trying to execute a DROP VIEW statement that is a result of a SELECT statement on a schedule

Tags: sql, select, view, scheduled-tasks

So I need to periodically drop views that are orphaned by jobs that have errored out in our application, to identify them I run the following query which generates a lot of DROP VIEW statements with the aforementioned views that need to be deleted.

```
SELECT 'DROP VIEW ' + TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'SEF_%'

SELECT 'DROP VIEW ' + TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'SCF_%'
```

My problem is I then need to run those DROP VIEW statements on a scheduled task, so running the SELECT statement isn't the issue (since I can schedule that), but that I also need to run the resultant queries from this on a schedule. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Per comment below, I forgot to mention that this was SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

Comment: Sounds like poor design. Do you create tables dynamically? For example  `SEF_date` or `SEF_id`?

Comment: That would be more of a question for our developers, I am just tasked with cleaning up the database after the fact.  Despite the fact that they found the problem they have not indicated whether they will in fact be implementing a fix to correctly purge these views if and when a job fails.

Comment: Which RDBMS you use?

Comment: My apologies that would have been good information to include, SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

You need to store result of query in variable and execute it.

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4cc52/2/0)**

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'DROP VIEW ' + TABLE_NAME + ';' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'SEF_%'
   OR TABLE_NAME LIKE 'SCF_%';

/* Debug */
SELECT @sql;

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
    @sql;
```

For future you should create views `WITH SCHEMABINDING` and enforce first to remove view then table.

Comment: I shall try this out later this evening off peak as I can't afford to drop views if end users are currently running jobs, I shall post my findings, thanks for the assistance.